# Frontend assets upload to folder (Craft 4)

Tags: assets, craft4, frontend, upload, frontend-form

I need to upload files into an asset folder I have created using a frontend form, however I can't seem to get this to work in Craft 4.

This is the code I have used:

```
<form method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      {{ csrfInput() }}
      {{ actionInput('assets/upload') }}
      {{ hiddenInput('folderId', 1) }}

      <input name="assets-upload" type='file'>
      <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

I keep getting: 400 error (bad request). What am I doing wrong?